# I want to add a group summary data into the formula field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a  account wise group and i want to find the maximum date accroding to the group so i created a summary field. I want to add the summary field in the formula.how can i do that help me.

Comment: what do you mean by adding summary field to formula?

Comment: To find the maximum date by group wise. i used the insert summary option.i want to add the summary in formula field.

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. go to formula workshop and double click Maximum summary field which is most effective way.
2. go to formula workshop and write as below

   Maximum ({Attendance.Date})

The syntax changes if its a group footer I have given it for report footer